# Spring Security authenticate user via post

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a react app running on a separate port (localhost:3000) that i want to use to authenticate users with, currently i have a proxy setup to my Spring backend (localhost:8080).

Can I somehow manually authenticate instead of `http.httpBasic()` by sending a `POST` request to my backend and getting back a session cookie then include the cookie with every request? It would simplify the auth process on iOS side aswell (using this process i could only store the session cookie value in keychain and pass it with every request made to my api)

How would I disable csrf for non-browser requests?

Is there a better approach to this? Diffrent paths for browser and mobile auth?

```
 {
   "username": "user",
   "password": "12345678"
 }
```

Handle the request in spring controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/web")
public String authenticateUser() {
    //Receive the auth data here... and perform auth
    //Send back session cookie
    return "Success?";
}
```

My **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebsecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final DetailService detailService;

    public WebsecurityConfig(DetailService detailService) {
        this.detailService = detailService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(detailService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/v1/authenticate/new").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/v1/authenticate/web").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(14);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think for non browser client you can implement Spring security token based authentication mechanism. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126201/spring-security-authentication-via-token

Comment: You can do with token based mechanism with JWT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49325692/how-to-implement-jwt-based-authentication-and-authorization-in-spring-security

Comment: @ShanmugaSundaramN JWT isn't made for sessions

Answer (score 0):

You can create an endpoint that takes user's credentials in a request body, perform authentication and then set tokens, and other required parameters in [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookies.

After setting cookies, subsequent requests can read access/refresh token from cookies and add it in requests, you can then use custom [CheckTokenEndpoint](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.html) to verify tokens.

In the following example `TokenParametersDto` is a POJO that has `username` and `password` properties.

For issuing token (by verifying credentials) you can delegate call to [TokenEndpoint#postAccessToken(....)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/5df8fc1e24261029c7fcb856b7766bcb32c7b98c/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.java#L86) or use its logic to your own method.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/oauth/http/token", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> issueToken(@RequestBody final @Valid @NotNull TokenParametersDto tokenParametersDto,
                                       final HttpServletResponse response) {

    final OAuth2AccessToken token = tokenService.issueToken(tokenParametersDto);

    storeTokenInCookie(token, response);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

private void storeTokenInCookie(final OAuth2AccessToken token, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    final Cookie accessToken = new Cookie("access_token", token.getValue());
    accessToken.setHttpOnly(true);
    accessToken.setSecure(sslEnabled);
    accessToken.setPath("/");
    accessToken.setMaxAge(cookieExpiration);

    final Cookie tokenType = new Cookie("token_type", token.getTokenType());
    tokenType.setHttpOnly(true);
    tokenType.setSecure(sslEnabled);
    tokenType.setPath("/");
    tokenType.setMaxAge(cookieExpiration);

    // Set Refresh Token and other required cookies.

    response.addCookie(accessToken);
    response.addCookie(tokenType);
}
```

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26239302/2801909) for disabling CSRF for a specific URL section.